# Commit message linking to issue AND issue link to commit

Tags: gitlab

How is it possible to linkg a **commit message** to **issue** **AND** the **issue** to the **commits**?

If I add in the commit message **#123** it is a link to the issue, but on the issue there is n**o link to the commit**.
Is this in any way possible to show the commit in the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems **GitLab** has now **added** this feature.

If you add to your **commit message** the **issue id** the **commit number** will be mentioned in the issue like this:
[image]

Links to docs:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#default-closing-pattern

Comment: Here is the link to the docs describing that https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html

Comment: Up-to-date links to GitLab docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references  and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#default-closing-pattern

Answer (score 5):

This [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13345) suggests:

> Simply write the commit sha (in the issue) and it will be linked automatically!

However, this is not done automatically, which means adding an issue in a commit won't add the commit in the issue.

You might have to setup a post-reveive hook in order for that hook to:

- detect a commit message a a reference to an issue
- use [GitLab API for Issues](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html) in order to add the commit SHA1 in the issue description.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very sad, that this feature is not out of the box.
I used FogBugz before and this was really awesome to have the direct links.

Comment: I didn't see that hook before, I will look again for it.

Answer (score 0):

Issues and commits can be crosslinked by adding the issue number to the commit https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/crosslinking_issues.html

> Every time you mention an issue in your commit message, you’re creating a relationship between the two stages of the development workflow: the issue itself and the first commit related to that issue.
>
> If the issue and the code you’re committing are both in the same project, you simply add #xxx to the commit message, where xxx is the issue number. If they are not in the same project, you can add the full URL to the issue (https://gitlab.com///issues/).
>
> ```
> git commit -m "this is my commit message. Ref #xxx"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> git commit -m "this is my commit message. Related to https://gitlab.com/<username>/<projectname>/issues/<xxx>"
> ```
>
> Of course, you can replace gitlab.com with the URL of your own GitLab instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for GitHub. Even though question has `GitLab` tag, this might be useful for users in `GitHub`.
You can add the issue to the commit by simply mentioning the issue number. Let's say the issue that you fixed has number 14.

You can commit like:

```sh
Add bla-bla to fix issue #34
```

And in the issue in `github.com`, simply comment on the conversation saying that, you fixed this issue with commit id `<commit id goes here>`. and it will look like this:

[image]